# Google Analytics: Enabled 'Track site search results' , where do I see list with search queries

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I enabled 'Track site search results' on Google Analytics and put also the queryparameter. Now my question is, where can I simply look at the list that is gathered with all the searches that are done by users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the new interface:
Content -> Site search -> Search terms